# Make will not compile efitools

Tags: command-line, uefi, make

Efitools will not compile due to this error:

```
simple_file.c:206:2: error: 'EFI_BOOT_SERVICES' has no member named 
'LocalHandleBuffer'
```

The source is here : [efitools repository](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/jejb/efitools.git;a=summary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to upgrade to a newer version of GNU-EFI. The `README` file for `efitools` specifies that you need version 3.0q or later. Ubuntu 12.10 comes with GNU-EFI 3.0i, which is pathetically out-of-date. It looks like an update to 3.0s is in the works for 13.04. In the meantime, you can install GNU-EFI from [source code,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnu-efi/) but then you'll need to tweak the `efitools` `Makefile` to refer to headers and libraries in `/usr/local` rather than in `/usr`.

Comment: is s later than q?

Comment: Yes; GNU-EFI uses numbers followed by a letter in the Roman alphabet, so it's 3.0q, then 3.0r, then 3.0s.

Comment: now security_policy.c wont compile. it gives a bunch of assembler registers

Comment: You probably need to install some sort of assembler tool. Unfortunately, I don't see anything mentioned explicitly in `README`. Ubuntu's got a meta-package called `build-essential` that installs lots of stuff, though, so you might start with that. As a side note, assembly code isn't actually necessary; it can be handled by use of `MSABI` instead. I've got a variant of this file in my rEFInd project (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind) that uses `MSABI` instead of assembly code. It's not a drop-in replacement, but if you're desperate, you might be able to study the changes to get one that works.